# Is there anything built into .NET/C# for copying values between objects?

Tags: c#, .net, copy

Suppose you have 2 classes like so:

```
public class ClassA {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Other { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Nope { get; set; }
}
```

Now imagine you have an instance of each class and you want to copy the values from a into b.  Is there something like MemberwiseClone that would copy the values where the property names match (and of course is fault tolerant -- one has a get, and the other a set, etc.)?

```
var a = new ClassA(); var b = new classB();
a.CopyTo(b); // ??
```

Something like this is pretty easy in a language like JavaScript.

I'm guessing the answer is no, but maybe there is a simple alternative too.  I have written a reflection library to do this, but if built in to C#/.NET at a lower level would probably be more efficient (and why re-invent the wheel).

Comment: have a look at AutoMapper: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's nothing in the framework for object-object mapping but there's a very popular library out there that does this:  [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

> AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively
>   complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to
>   another. This type of code is rather dreary and boring to write, so
>   why not invent a tool to do it for us?

By the way, just for learning, here's a *simple* way you can implement what you want. I haven't tested it thoroughly, and it's nowhere as robust / flexible / performant as AutoMapper, but hopefully there's something to get out of the general idea:

```
public void CopyTo(this object source, object target)
{
    // Argument-checking here...

    // Collect compatible properties and source values
    var tuples = from sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties()
                 join targetProperty in target.GetType().GetProperties() 
                                     on sourceProperty.Name 
                                     equals targetProperty.Name

                 // Exclude indexers
                 where !sourceProperty.GetIndexParameters().Any()
                    && !targetProperty.GetIndexParameters().Any()

                 // Must be able to read from source and write to target.
                 where sourceProperty.CanRead && targetProperty.CanWrite

                 // Property types must be compatible.
                 where targetProperty.PropertyType
                                     .IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType)

                 select new
                 {
                     Value = sourceProperty.GetValue(source, null),
                     Property = targetProperty
                 };

    // Copy values over to target.
    foreach (var valuePropertyTuple in tuples)
    {
        valuePropertyTuple.Property
                          .SetValue(target, valuePropertyTuple.Value, null);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like this in .NET that I'm aware of, but one library that is able to do this (and much more) is [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). For your case, something like:

```
_mapper.Map<A, B> (a, b);
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know this does not exist. The way I have been doing it is by:

```
public static T DeepCopy(T oldclass)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, oldclass);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See the interface [`System.ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx), and the method [`System.Object.MemberwiseClone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx). As noted in the MSDN docs,

> The **MemberwiseClone** method creates a shallow copy by creating a new object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to the new object. If a field is a value type, a bit-by-bit copy of the field is performed. If a field is a reference type, the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object and its clone refer to the same object.

Comment: So you say this would work? `classB =  classA.MemberwiseClone() as classB`